# Classic ASP: Please Wait page while processing code

Tags: asp-classic

A form on `page1.asp` submits to `page2.asp`. Page2 takes say a minute to do it's work.

To the end user, the browser stays on page1 while it waits for the response from page2.

How can I show a please wait page instead - is the best way just using javascript to change page1 to say Please Wait when the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just display your Please Wait `onClick` when the user browses to the next page, and then make sure to set `Response.buffer = True` in your Page 2. That will prevent any server output from going to the browser until the page is finished processing.

Comment: Thought so, javascript being the best way