# Loading window in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a button in the form in a page1.asp.
I am getting getting response from page2.asp after form submission.

It is take sometime for processing data in page2.asp.
User stays at page1 and clicking the button again and again.

so I want to have an "Loading window" while data processing and user could not click the Button again.

please help me to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

AGM Raja

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classic ASP: Please Wait page while processing code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733896/classic-asp-please-wait-page-while-processing-code)

Answer (score 2):

You can use submit button's "onclick" event both to disable the button (so user won't be able to click it again) and to display "Loading..." message to the user.

At the very simplest you can display the message in the button itself, e.g.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Please wait...'" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t4f3T/

*UPDATE*

I don't know why it worked in my own tests, but Shadow Wizard pointed errors of my way: Form will not be submitted by disabled button, you have to add `form.submit()` yourself:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Please wait...';form.submit()" />
```

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/t4f3T/2/

Comment: Hi Yuriy,
This is not submitting to the Page2.asp.
It disabling the Button and Text is changing,but not going to the Response page.

Comment: @AGMRaja Can you post HTML for the form? If it's too big, just abbreviate to the form and button elements

Comment: This modification should interfere with form submit. *Unless* it is currently done via `onclick`. That would mean `onclick` is already being used by an existing function and if that's the case you will have to add code `this.disabled=true;this.value='Please wait...'` to that function

Comment: @AGMRaja is correct. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4f3T/1/) - disabling the submit button in its onclick cause the form not to be submitted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for downvoting, it was a humbling experience. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Cheers @Yuriy now it's not wrong but still can be improved. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4f3T/3/) is what I have in mind. (Disabling the submit button in the form submit event :))